# Haar measure for $U(2) / \left( U(1) \right)^2$

Tags: group-theory, haar-measure

This is my first time in calculating this stuff so I would like to understand why the Haar measure on the group $U(2) / \left( U(1) \right)^2$ is deduced from:

$$
U^\dagger dU = -i \begin{pmatrix} \sin^2\phi & i\gamma \\ -i\bar{\gamma} &  \cos^2\phi\end{pmatrix},
$$

with $\gamma=d\phi+i\sin\phi\cos\phi d\lambda$, to be

$$
\mu(U^\dagger dU)= \sin\phi\cos\phi d\phi d\lambda.
$$

And mos importantly, how do I compute it? (Everyone says it is easy and trivial but no one actually does it.)

Comment: You might want to have a look into "Abstract Harmonic Analysis" by Hewitt & Ross. In the first volume of this book they compute the Haar measure of several locally compact groups.

Comment: This quotient isn't a group, so it doesn't have a Haar measure.